# std::cin >> vector[i] won't let iterators work properly?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator, cin

I've been wondering why my `std::vector<int>` wasn't getting sorted, and I've realized that `myVector.begin()` and `myVector.end()` were same value (first index) when using `std::cin >> myVector[i]`

Take a look at the sample code that I've just created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
    int N;
    // take size
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    myVector.reserve(N);

    // take input
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // this messes up iterators?
        std::cin >> myVector[i];

        // this works
        // int intput;
        // std::cin >> input;
        // myVector.push_back(input);
    }

    // iterators not working properly
    std::cout << *(myVector.begin()) << std::endl; // outputs first index
    std::cout << *(myVector.end()) << std::endl; // outputs first index!?

    // sort
    // std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

output:

```
4
4
```

expected output:

```
4
0
```

So, my question is, does `std::cin >> myVector[i]` mess up iterators? and why does `push_back` work not and `[]operators`?

Thanks

Comment: `*(myVector.end())` is never valid.

Comment: `push_back()` inserts a new element which is fine. `[i]` when `i` is out of bounds causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reserve()` just preallocates space, so that subsequent appends will not require (as many) reallocations -- it doesn't *resize* the vector.  To resize it, you need... `resize()`.  :)

`std::vector<T>` separately tracks its own *size* (number of elements) and *capacity* (largest number of elements that it could contain without a reallocation being needed).  The easiest way to see that `reserve()` doesn't change the size is by calling `size()` on the vector after `reserve()`.  You'll see the vector still "believes" its size is 0.